# Breaking Google Play developer policy in this case or not?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to earn some money with android applications, but I'm facing a big problem. Google does not support my country on Google Play ( for merchants ). So I can't use their payment system for selling apps or in-app goods. Also they have a policy that say, we developers cannot use third- party payment system (like PayPal) in application published on Google Play.

But I want to know if this is "legal" for doing this.

1. I publish my DEMO application on google play
2. Via in app I inform app users that there is a FULL application on my website
3. User navigates to my website and pays for full app (via paypal or other payment system )

[Google Play Developer Policy Link](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)

Quote from Google Play Policy:

> Paid and Free Applications App purchases: Developers charging for
>   applications and downloads from Google Play must do so by using Google
>   Play's payment system. In-app purchases: Developers offering virtual
>   goods or currencies within a game downloaded from Google Play must use
>   Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment.
>   Developers offering additional content, services or functionality
>   within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use
>   Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment, except:
>   where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g. buying
>   movie tickets, or buying a publication where the price also includes a
>   hard copy subscription); or where payment is for digital content or
>   goods that may be consumed outside of the application itself (e.g.
>   buying songs that can be played on other music players). Developers
>   must not mislead users about the applications they are selling nor
>   about any in-app services, goods, content or functionality they are
>   selling.

Please advise me. Thank you!

Comment: Other than accepted answer, I'd love to find out how other devs is "lesser" countries deal with this - South Africa e.g. has no way to charge for apps either. (apologies to those saying this is OT)

Comment: [We are not Google, nor are we lawyers. Hire a lawyer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19886/not-the-place-for-legal-questions)

Comment: "We are not lawyers, we do not know the details of your situation and the law of the country you live in. Hire a lawyer."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this.

> Developers offering additional **content, services or functionality** within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment

Directing users to a 3rd party site to buy the app is surely one of these. 
Moreover:

> Content Policies
>
> Our content policies **apply to any content** your application displays or links to, including any ads it shows to users and any user-generated content it hosts or links to. Further, they apply to any content from your developer account which is publicly displayed in Google Play

an extract from Developer Distribution Agreement (for better clarification):

> 4.5 Non-Compete. You may not use the Market to distribute or make available any Product whose primary purpose is to facilitate the distribution of software applications and games for use on Android devices outside of the Market.

I'd say that demo's primary purpose is to facilitate the distribution of software applications and games.

Comment: you have missed part of the quote that may be important - "except: ... where payment is for digital...goods that may be consumed outside of the application itself" - I'd say surely another app in "being consumed" outside of this app.

Comment: further that first quote refers to "another category of app downloaded from Google Play" - the OP has another app that is downloaded from a different site. (not arguing with you - truly analysing the answer to gain full clarity)

Comment: I've added an extract from the Developer Distribution Agreement for better clarification. Of course there is a field for interpretation here.

Comment: +1 That looks like a solid "NO" from the non-compete side. (thx for quick answer before the expected flagging of this ??)