# Selling custom product that doesn't fit well for in app purchase

Tags: google-play, payment, policy

I'am working on community project for chess players and I use standard in app purchases provided by Google to get credit for functions to be used. I prefer however one big payment for one country (culture) made by some company or major local chess entity, personally dealing conditions, creating data source to fit my app, giving users everything within the culture for free and in return giving the sponsor place in various screens of my application.

- I know 3rd party payment processors are not allowed for standard app use.
  [Breaking Google Play developer policy in this case or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268465/breaking-google-play-developer-policy-in-this-case-or-not)
- Making in app purchase for this is just weird.

How to get money for such a product not breaking Google play rules?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a policy question and not a programming question

Answer (score 1):

There's [a whole website by Google explaining the policies](https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/).

I don't work for Google's policy team, and I'm not a lawyer, but here would be my reading:

- If you want a user to pay within your app, then use Google's methods. So if you want the person sponsoring the whole country to pay within the App, use Google's payment methods.
- What you do as a company to strike sponsorship deals and take payment is up to you, if that payment happens outside the app.

But you should read that website above carefully for yourself, and of course Google Play has the final say.